# cannot send response out of db.query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
router.get('/detalle/(:id)', (req, res) => {
    let vehiculo_base
    db.query("select b.nombre, count(b.nombre) AS n_vehiculos from base AS b, vehiculo AS v where b.id = v.id_base AND b.id_flota = " + req.params.id , function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err
        vehiculo_base = result
    })
    res.send(vehiculo_base)
})
```

I want to add multiple query results to the response, but the variable vehiculo_base is undefined out of db.query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that query is async, and you are returning the result with `res.send` right after executing it synchronously.

You should return the result once it is available.

```
router.get('/detalle/(:id)', (req, res) => {
    db.query("select b.nombre, count(b.nombre) AS n_vehiculos from base AS b, vehiculo AS v where b.id = v.id_base AND b.id_flota = " + req.params.id , function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err
        res.send(result)
    })
    
})
```

You should add logs in the future to understand the flow, and read a bit about async and sync execution. And how javascript execution works.

Answer (score 0):

db.query is async function so try like this.

```js
router.get('/detalle/(:id)', (req, res) => {
    let vehiculo_base
    db.query("select b.nombre, count(b.nombre) AS n_vehiculos from base AS b, vehiculo AS v where b.id = v.id_base AND b.id_flota = " + req.params.id , function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err
        vehiculo_base = result
        res.send(vehiculo_base)
    })
})
```

second approach

```js
router.get('/detalle/(:id)', async (req, res) => {
      let vehiculo_base
      var vehiculo_base = await db.query("select b.nombre, count(b.nombre) AS n_vehiculos from base AS b, vehiculo AS v where b.id = v.id_base AND b.id_flota = " + req.params.id);
       res.send(vehiculo_base)
  })
```

Comment: Hi, only the second option should work for me but this happens:
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Query'
    |     property '_timer' -> object with constructor 'Timer'
    --- property '_object' closes the circle

Do you know what this means and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this route as

```
router.get('/detalle/(:id)', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    let vehiculo_base = await 
    db.query("select b.nombre, count(b.nombre) AS n_vehiculos from base AS b, vehiculo AS v where b.id = v.id_base AND b.id_flota = " + req.params.id)
    res.send(vehiculo_base);
  }catch(error){
    res.send(error);
  }   
});
```